# Is logitech driving force gt plug and play?

Tags: controllers, euro-truck-simulator-2

I will be buying logitech driving force gt tomorrow.

Since this is a second hand and is first released over a decade ago, I quite have a doubt that it still works fine.

Upon buying it, I will bring a Windows laptop and a MacBook Pro with Euro Truck Simulator 2 to test it.

Now the question is, upon testing it, will I just plug it in and it must work with the game immediately or do I have some installations/configurations to make it work?

How will I know it does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will I just plug it in and it must work with the game immediately or do I have some installations/configurations to make it work?

With American Truck Simulator and Euro Truck Simulator 2, you need to configure all of the controllers at least once.

> How will I know it does work?

For both American Truck Simulator and Euro Truck Simulator 2, all types of controllers work on Windows as long as they are DirectInput (PS2/4 and other unlicensed peripherals) or XInput (Xbox 360/One licensed only).

For the Driving Force GT, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logitech_Driving_Force_GT#Microsoft_Windows) lists ATS and ETS2 as compatible.